# How do you preserve existing data and re-open a iframe in a chrome extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have dug through a number of posts here and looked over google labs info on chrome extensions and was unable to find any good leads. If I have a extension that opens a iFrame and within the iFrame I perform a login and then do some navigation is there any way for me to return to where I was when I re-open the extension? When I re-open my extension now I have to re-login and navigate back to where I was. I suppose I can do some kind of trickery with a cookie, but if there is a better option available I would like to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome extensions works pretty much as pages.

You can use cookies, even localStorage in the same way you'd do with a normal page.

There is no "special way" to do what you intended to do.

Comment: I ended up doing just that with local storage. I am surprised there is not a better way.

Comment: Yes, all the history API thing is pretty primitive, there's still no way to get the tab history, for example, to save the state and open the tab later.  Google's programmers aren't focusing that area right now.